# Custom Font saying (none installed) in an ios application

Tags: ios, swift

i am new to swift and iOS and i am facing an issue with custom fonts provided by the application.
i have added an font to the application but now when i go to assign it to any label or any text it doesn't allow to use custom font option by saying (none installed)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jwayN.png)

Comment: How you added them into project?

Comment: This will help you https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/text_display_and_fonts/adding_a_custom_font_to_your_app

Comment: @Meesum-naqvi have you got our answer from my answer post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Add fonts to your project.
2. Then select target membership to yes.

[image]

3. Go to info.plist add key "Fonts provided by application".

[image]

4.select font from custom and apply it.

for more info please check this link https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/text_display_and_fonts/adding_a_custom_font_to_your_app